# Is a constructor implicitly declared in the case of a abstract class with no data members?

Tags: c++, constructor

If a class is only used as a base class to derive other classes and therefore has only pure virtual member functions (no data members) - does it get an implicitly declared constructor?

```
    class Object {
    public:
     virtual void show(std::ostream&) = 0;
     virtual ~Object();
    };
```

Comment: The Q is not a duplicate of the one that is marked. This Q specifically askes about the existance of a default constructor for abstract classes without any members, that is not answered in that Q.

Comment: @hsalimi It doesn't make any difference. The rules are the same for all classes. There are no special cases.